# Display another page's content without changing url for drupal 8

Tags: navigation

I want to display another page's content without changing url for drupal 8 . 
In drupal 7 I used menu_execute_active_handler() , but drupal 8 this function is not available. 
I got a solution from drupal forum , but properly not working for me. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1591618

Please any one provide me example code for this.

Comment: Why not create an alias?

Comment: I create a custom page /home and make it at front page from backend .

Now this custom page call back I wrote a logic i.e if user is not login then render user login from. If user is login I want to render here another page ..

So after login user redirect to home page  , but it look like url is not change.. 
In drupal 7 I used menu_execute_active_handler, but drupal 8 I am facing problem.